# side menu is not working on ionic serve

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic2

My side menu was working fine. But, suddenly it is not working anymore. I am not sure what is the issue. Here is my html, CSS and inspect element code.

My .html file looks like this

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>      
      <img src="assets/images/home/KmartText.png">
    </ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="takeToCart();">
          <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
          <div class="qntyColor">{{cartCount}}</div>
      </button>    
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

.css file looks like this

```
 //image size
    ion-title img{
        height: 35px;
        width: 35%;
    }

    //image center
    ion-title{
        text-align: center;
    }

    //ion-navbar backgroundcolor for android and ios
    .toolbar-background-md{
        background: $background-header;
    }
    .toolbar-background-ios{
        background: $background-header;
    }

    //applying color for icons in header
    ion-navbar button ion-icon{
        color: white;
    }
```

When I give inspect element on sidemenu button, I am getting this code:

```
<button icon-only="" ion-button="" menutoggle="" class="bar-buttons bar-buttons-md disable-hover bar-button bar-button-md bar-button-menutoggle bar-button-menutoggle-md bar-button-default bar-button-default-md" tappable=""><span class="button-inner">
      <ion-icon name="menu" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-md-menu" aria-label="menu" ng-reflect-name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </span><div class="button-effect" style="transform: translate3d(-4px, -19px, 0px) scale(1); height: 71px; width: 71px; opacity: 0; transition: transform 273ms, opacity 191ms 82ms;"></div></button>
```

**Update:**
I created a new project and implemented only side menu. I inspected menu element and got this:

```
<button icon-only="" ion-button="" menutoggle="" class="disable-hover bar-buttons bar-buttons-md bar-button bar-button-md bar-button-default bar-button-default-md bar-button-menutoggle bar-button-menutoggle-md"><span class="button-inner">
        <ion-icon name="menu" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-md-menu" aria-label="menu" ng-reflect-name="menu"></ion-icon> 
    </span><div class="button-effect" style="transform: translate3d(-28px, -24px, 0px) scale(1); height: 76px; width: 76px; opacity: 0; transition: transform 273ms, opacity 191ms 82ms;"></div></button>
```

> There is some difference in the both inspect element codes.

Comment: "suddenly not working" meaning errors in log? or button click fails?

Comment: no errors two days before my ionic serve was not working but in my device side menu was working but now both browser and mobile is not working i have not touched anything in the side menu part @suraj

Comment: did you update ionic 2 recently?

Comment: yes  i did but what is the problem with that

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-behavior-of-icons-in-buttons according to rc0 breaking changes you should not have `icon-only` with menutoggle. Try and let me know

Comment: @suraj yes i tryed but i am stil getting the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136807/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).